# Click event doesn't work when css animation ends on iOS 15

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, css-animations

I have a simple React project with a modal with a fade-in effect applied.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-popuptest-q0bn0d

The modal window has a close button, but in iOS 14-15, the modal does not disappear when I click the button when the fade effect ends.

https://youtu.be/BLYgK08BZkU

- This video was shot on ipadOS 14, but the same thing happens on iOS 15
- But it doesn't happen on iOS 16 or Android

Here's a video. I clicked slowly the first three times, then quickly clicked the next three times, and both worked well.
However, when I click at the end of the fade effect in the second half of the video (especially from 0:18), the window does not close.

Why is this issue occurring? Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
// App.tsx

const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

const closeModal = () => {
  console.log("closeModal");
  setShowModal(false);
};

<Modal
  title={"ModalTitle"}
  show={showModal}
  close={closeModal}
  children={ModalBody}
/>

// Modal.tsx

<a
  href="#"
  className="close"
  onClick={close}
  style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
>
```

Click not working in css animated popup in React project

Comment: Have you tried using a `button` instead of an `a` tag?

Comment: @RicoHancock Yes I tried the button, a and div tags but all have the same problem